# Phonegap : Embed YoutubePlayer in iPad-App

Tags: cordova, youtube-api

I'd like to use a youtube player in my Phonegap-iPad-App. 
The iframe tag doesn't work understandably. But all other embed / object-Tags I found already, don't work either.

Does anyone have a working solution at hand?
I use Phonegap 1.1.0, iOS SDK 5.0 on an iPad 1.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: from what I know(I don't own an ipad), it doesn't support flash, in this case, you need to somehow tell youtube that you want it to run videos using the HTML 5 "video" tag

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://www.youtube.com/html5.
Maybe you can hack something from it, but ther's no official way yet.